# Excel bug message box output writes on cell

Tags: vba, excel

On one of my Excel projects I have a "saving check" feature that if the workbook has not been saved in the past 25 min it will prompt user to take some action (`MsgBox`).

This method invokes `Application.OnTime` to schedule next alert and is being rescheduled once is saved.

Today we saw a bug where the contents of the message box (and additional text with "Microsoft Excel" & "OK") were printed out to a worksheet, overwriting cell contents.

According to the user no macro was running in the background and the only action being taken was switching between worksheets. Those sheets have no event triggered code.

I though `OnTime` was safe method but that bug just freaked me out.

I have done some research trying to find documentation about this issue but couldn't. I believe it must be a low prob event that might happens once in a lifetime.

Any comments about if I should I keep this code or wipe it out?
Many thanks in advance.

' EDIT 1 - Adding code being called by the `OnTime` Function

```
Public Sub NeedToBeSaved()
' ======================================================================
' Description : Periodically checks if the workbook needs to be saved.
'
' Comments    : AfterSave method takes care of scheduling new check.
'               Refresh it only if user has not saved
' ======================================================================
    Dim nme As Name
    Dim dteLastSaved As Date

    Set nme = ThisWorkbook.Names(gsRNGNAME_LASTSAVED)
    dteLastSaved = Mid$(nme.value, 2)

    ' Debug Log
    ' ---------
    Debug.Print "----------------------"
    Debug.Print "Saving Periodic Check"
    Debug.Print "----------------------"
    Debug.Print "Worbook is saved:" & vbTab & ThisWorkbook.saved
    Debug.Print "Last time       :" & vbTab & dteLastSaved

    If (ThisWorkbook.saved = False) Then
        MsgBox "File has not been saved in the last " & glAPP_SAVED_FREQ & _
                " minutes, please consider saving your changes. " & _
                vbCrLf & "(To prevent this message open in read-only mode)"

        Call SaveOnTimeCheck

    Else
        Debug.Print "Not rescheduled"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Charlie - you need to edit the quesiton and include the code with `OnTime` call.

Comment: "Overwriting cell contents" -- do you mean that the cells' contents were obscured/overwritten on the screen, or that the actual cell contents were changed?

Comment: Gonna add the code I am using gimme a sec.
The issue is that the actual cell contents were changed by the string that should be printed out in the message box.

Comment: How good is your virus protection?

Comment: That's actually a good point. I've been running multiple checks in 2 different computers. Not sure though if the computer in question have different security policy. Will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most likely scenario to me:

Imagine someone does some copy paste actions in your workbook. He doesn't look on the screen but on his keyboard because he's not familiar with typing blind. The MsgBox pops up (he doesn't notice, still eyes on keybord). He accidentally copies the content of the MsgBox <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and pastes it into the workbook.

This adds an additional "Microsoft Excel" and lines "---" and "OK" to the message like below:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Excel
---------------------------
Your MsgBox message here …
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

You can easily reproduce this yourself by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> while a MsgBox is up. And pasting it into Excel afterwards.

There are 2 possible reasons for this:

1. The manual copy paste scenario I described above (most likely).
2. Alternatively there was a macro running in the background doing copy paste actions while the MsgBox was up (I'm not 100 % sure but I think this is even not possible, but if so you should be able to reproduce the issue).

Comment: Lol that exactly the message... I've never checked if you could copy values from the message box (clap clap). I just confirmed with the user and he says that he was indeed trying to copy/paste just in time.
Many thanks for the answer!